# MVC3 Save Search Results while changing pages

Tags: asp.net-mvc-3

I have a search page where you can search for customer based on name, phone number, account number, or customer number.  I then look through 7 different databases to try to match on these things to bring back results.  Because of this I would rather only run the search once and remember the results which I can then display in pages.  Below is the ViewModel I use for my SearchResults page.

```
public class SearchResultsViewModel
{
    public IEnumerable<CustomerSearchResults> SearchResults { get; set; }
    public PagingInfo PagingInfo { get; set; }
}


public class PagingInfo
{
    public int TotalItems { get; set; }
    public int ItemsPerPage { get; set; }
    public int CurrentPage { get; set; }

    public int TotalPages {
        get { return (int)Math.Ceiling((decimal)TotalItems / ItemsPerPage); }
    }
}
```

Here is the controller code for the SearchResults Page

```
public ActionResult SearchResults(int page = 1)
    {
        SearchResultsViewModel srvm = new SearchResultsViewModel
        {
            SearchResults = res.Skip((page - 1) * pageSize).Take(pageSize),
            PagingInfo = new PagingInfo { CurrentPage = page, ItemsPerPage = pageSize, TotalItems = res.Count() }
        };
        ViewBag.CurrentPage = page;
        return View("SearchResults", srvm);
    }

    [HttpPost]
    public ActionResult Index(IndexViewModel vm)
    {
        res = GetSearchResults(vm);
        return SearchResults();
    }
```

res is a global variable in the controller.  I was thinking maybe I could save the data that way to show on the different pages but found out rather quickly that I get a new controller each time I pull up a view so this does not work.

The View Codes just displays search results in a table and has an HTML helper at the bottom which shows page number links.  The page number links are anchors calling the SearchResults action with the correct page number.

Can I save the data to use form page to page or is this impossible?  Is there a better way for me to do this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can store the results in TempData.

```
public ActionResult SearchResults(int page = 1)
{
    res = (SearchResults)TempData["results"];
    SearchResultsViewModel srvm = new SearchResultsViewModel
    {
        SearchResults = res.Skip((page - 1) * pageSize).Take(pageSize),
        PagingInfo = new PagingInfo { CurrentPage = page, ItemsPerPage = pageSize, TotalItems = res.Count() }
    };
    ViewBag.CurrentPage = page;
    TempData["results"] = res;
    return View("SearchResults", srvm);
}

[HttpPost]
public ActionResult Index(IndexViewModel vm)
{
    res = GetSearchResults(vm);
    TempData["results"] = res;
    return SearchResults();
}
```

You can do the same thing with Session state and then you don't have to save it back at the end of each action, but you have some additional overhead with that and you have to make sure to get rid of it when you're done, or you could have some funky results later on. Just some things to watch out for.

Comment: That solution worked great.  I am a relative newbie when it comes to web programmign so I am still learnign all the mechanisms that are available.  Thanks for the help.

Answer (score 0):

How about caching it, one example is through [Windows AppFabric](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/windowsserver/ee695849)